# app crashs on device(ios 6) after updating google plus and facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

app runs perfectly in simulator and iPad(iOS 8)  but crashes in device
IPod(iOS 6)[only splash screen shows and the get given below error log]

```
 dyld`dyld_fatal_error:(on thread1 0 dyld_fatal_error)
   ->  0x2fe840c4 <+0>: trap  (Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xe7ffdfe) 
       0x2fe840c8 <+4>: nop    

dyld: Symbol not found: _NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/9670AF5D-D81B-4805-AD66-631F6EFB3CB5/passenger.app/passenger
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
in /var/mobile/Applications/9670AF5D-D81B-4805-AD66-631F6EFB3CB5/passenger.app/passenger
```

somebody can help me to fix this issue i tried a lot but didnt get solution.i  cannt decide this problem is releated to ios 6 or device IPod(2nd Genration).

Answer (score 0):

[It's Facebook SDK 4.0.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x#4_0)

> iOS 6 is no longer supported. The FacebookSDK for iOS v4.0 requires
>   iOS 7 or higher.